# Mapzen custom markers or overlays on map

Tags: android, sdk, maps, markers, mapzen

Is there any possible method to draw custom overlays or switch up the default markers on the Android Mapzen SDK? I just need to be able to differentiate two different locations on a map using different-looking markers.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial solution:

To use two different markers (an active and inactive default marker), use mapzenMap.drawRoutePins(LngLat start, LngLat end). One marker will be grey, the other will be black.